# Is the following simplification of the running time of an algorithm given in Big-O notation correct?

Tags: analysis, algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I have given an algorithm that solves a system depending on the parameters $m$ and $n$ in time $O(m)^{(m+1)^2}O(n)^{m(m+1)}log^2(mn)$. I am interested in the running time of the algorithm for all $n$ when we restrict ourselves to the case where $m=2$. How do I compute the new runningtime of the algorithm?

I was thinking about the following simplifications:
$O(m)^{(m+1)^2}=O(2)^9=O(1)^9=O(1)$

$O(n)^{m(m+1)}=O(n)^6$ and

$log^2(mn)=log^2(2n)$

Which yields a running time of $O(1)O(n)^6log^2(2n)$.

Is this line of thought correct?

Comment: yes assuming that m is indeed constant = 2, you should also remove the constant terms to get $\mathbf{O}(n^6log^2(n))$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. Is it true that when multiplying Big-O notations I can simply put them together? So $O(f(x))*O(g(x))=O(f(x)g(x))$

Comment: yes, you can and should

Comment: Great! Thank you!